# Find the count of exact word even if it appears multiple times per line

Tags: shell, count, grep

I am trying to count the exact word appearance in a file even if it is repeated multiple times in a line using grep in a shell script.
I've tried :

```
grep -o $anyword $file |wc -l
```

and

```
grep -iw $anyword $file |wc -l
```

both did not work.

Example, the count for "word"

INPUT FILE:

```
bla bla Word blabla WORD

word bla boa

boa word bla word2
```

The Output should be:

```
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper **grep** approach:

```
grep -iwo 'word' file | wc -l
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="word") c++} END{print c}' inputfile
4
```

Comment: could you please provide a solution using grep!

Comment: @Zain add to your question that this is a requirement. Also define meaning of word.